# ORA-17627:invalid username/password;logon denied error message when trying to duplicate database in data broker

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, dataguard

I'm trying to duplicate the database for the purpose of Data broker in windows platform. When I'm trying to duplicate using below command

```
DUPLICATE TARGET DATABASE TO LOCALDEV FROM ACTIVE DATABASE;
```

I'm getting error as :

```
ORA-17629:Cannot connect to the remote database server
ORA-17627:invalid username/password;logon denied
ORA-17629:Cannot connect to the remote database server
```

I copied the password file from primary to standby and used same password as that of primary in standby. Still I'm facing this issue.
I'm able tnsping from both primary and standby.
I tried all the ways. But nothing could help me.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Show how you've connected on rman. I think you need to connect to both databases when you connect in rman.

Comment: check the entries of tnsnames.ora files of both databases

Comment: @RenatoAfonso  Thanks for your comments. I were able to resolve this issue. The problem were within the password file. I created a new password file in standby db with the same password as that of primary db and this issue was resolved.

Comment: @miracle173 Thanks for your comments. I were able to resolve this issue. The problem were within the password file. I created a new password file in standby db with the same password as that of primary db and this issue was resolved

Comment: That I don't understand because copying the password file should be sufficient.

Comment: @miracle173 I created the db in standby using different password as that of primary db and copied the password file as that of primary to standby. But still some issues were there and the above error message were showing. So I deleted the existing password file and created a new password file using command. Then I was able to duplicate the primary to standby db.